# Can Modules access variables stored in other modules that have not been imported, but both modules are exported to a main file?

Tags: javascript, module

I am a beginner in the world of JavaScript, and I am just learning about modules and how to use them.
Here is the situation:
I have a `main.js` file and two module#.js files, `module1.js` and `module2.js`.

```
project/
    main.js
    modules/
        module1.js
        module2.js
```

These files have both been individually imported into `main.js`, but `module2.js` contains a function `displayAll()` that is meant to display all the items in an array `items = [item1, item2, item3]`.

```
function displayAll() {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  console.log(`Item ${i} is ${items[i]}`)
  }
}
```

This is not exactly how it looks, but that is beside the point. My question is **since the above function is contained in `module2.js`, how do let it access the array `items` that is contained in `module1.js`?** What if another file needed it? How could I export it to multiple files without creating a messy web of imports?
I am not familiar with any frameworks yet, so please only use core javascript as much as possible.
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of project are you doing, which module format does it use? Commonjs modules (with `module.exports` and `require`) or ES6 (with `export` and `import`)? Or are you using plain JS files on a web page where everything is global?

Comment: Make the `items` a parameter of `displayAll`, and then call the function from the one module with the value from the other module as the argument. If they are separate modules and do not import each other, they must not interact directly - if they need to (should) know about each other, they would use imports.

Comment: I'm using ES6 `import` and `export`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a function that loads what you need.

In module2.js, you create this function that appends the module1.js to it

```
function loadJS(callback) {                
    var firstScriptElem = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0], script = document.createElement('script');

    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = module1.js; 
    script.async = false; 

    // Binds the event to the callback function. We use more than one event for cross browser compatibility.
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;

    firstScriptElem.appendChild(script);       

};
```

You then need to create a callback function that actually runs the code you want to run after retrieving module1.js

```
function callBack() {
// get your array

// do something with the array

}
```

Now in module2 you call `loadJS(callBack)` and there you have it.

Now I know you are new and don't want to dive into frameworks yet. But I should mention to you that requireJS does all of this very simply. I was using the kind of code above for a while but once I started using requireJS, I realize I should have used it from the beginning because its way more organized and you definitely don't have to repeat yourself with it. Makes module management easier (I too, only recently started learning the module patterns in javascript).

Comment: **Thanks!** I will soon try this out. I am thinking about learning AngularJS or ReactJS. Is there anything similar to the code you mentioned in RequireJS that would make this easier that belongs to the ReactJS and AngluarJS library and framework?

Comment: If it's AngularJS (Angular 1) then RequireJS works very well with that. Angular (Angular 2+) doesn't quite gel together with Require as well though, but it works well with SystemJS which I find easier to setup than Webpack, but that may be just me. I have not had the chance to play with React yet so I can't really comment on that.